# I would like to change the label for the x axis with Euclide package

Tags: labels, tkz-euclide

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=180]
%\tkzGrid[sub]

\tikzset{xaxe style/.style = {Stealth-Stealth},
        yaxe style/.style = {Stealth-Stealth},
        xlabel style/.append style={rotate=-30},
        %ylabel style/.append style={rotate=-30},
        }

\tkzInit[xmin=-50, xmax=50,ymin=-50, ymax=50, xstep=10, ystep=10]
\tkzLabelX[orig=false, text=blue, below = 5pt, font=\tiny]
%\tkzLabelY[orig=false, text=blue, left = 5pt, font=\tiny]


\tkzDrawX[right space=.5, left space=.5] %lungimi suplimentare la varful sagetilor
\tkzDrawY[up space=.5, down space=.5] %lungimi suplimentare la varful sagetilor



\tkzText[](-55.5,2.5){$y_1$}
\tkzText[](2.5,-55){$z$}

\tkzDefPoints{0/0/o}
\tkzLabelPoints[below right](o)
```

[image]

I would like to change the label for the x axis.
current form: 50, 40, .... , -50 (see picture).
desired shape: 50, 40, .... , 50.

Comment: would it be okay to use plain `Tikz` for the axes labelling